# loop trough whole array inside a field

Tags: templating, matrix, forloop

I want to write an entire loop into a field like this:

[image]

Obviously this is not working. What would be the correct syntax when twig is written inside a field?

Also is there a name for the twig tags inside a field? I have a hard time searching the interwebz for this.

Comment: For Twig filters as they are what I think you mean checkout: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html 
Most PHP functions / Filters are supported by twig so might take a look there aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by using this: `{{ include(template_from_string(entry.fieldName)|raw) }}`

You could also try it with just `|raw` But that probably only works for just HTML

This works on both a Plain Textfield aswell on a Richtext area. Although I wouldn't recommend putting code in your textfield's like that.

The original answer on a simular question can be found here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1270/3848